# What is XCode's group alternative in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have create c++ project in xcode, organized classes in folders and added those folders as groups in xcode. So, I can include header files directly by their names without complete path.
Now I want to use those organized classes in Visual Studio. But, visual studio can't find include files directly by files' name, it needs complete path.
So, is there any alternative to XCode's groups in Visual Studio?

Comment: Maybe the include path?

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. In XCode, dragging a folder to the project will ask you if you want it as a group..., and in Visual Studio we'll have to include paths to folders manually!